# Как в windows C программа может определить максимально занимаемую ей память?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, память

В Linux из файла /proc/self/status программа может прочитать (наряду с кучей других) строки с данными о себе:

*VmPeak: Peak virtual memory size.*

и

*VmHWM: Peak resident set size ("high water mark").*

Есть ли (я не имею в виду /proc) в Windows возможность получить аналогичную информацию ?

Comment: я бы такое сразу на стеке спрашивал =)

Comment: я бы такое сразу на стеке спрашивал =)

Совсем не понял.

Comment: @avp Наверное, имеется в виду stackoverflow.com

Comment: Аааа..., ну, я был уверен (и как показал @fogbit не ошибся), что на родном языке мне лучше помогут.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OpenProcess` + `GetProcessMemoryInfo`

подробнее: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-262506.html

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть.

Comment: ОК. 

PeakWorkingSetSize: 10887168  WorkingSetSize 864256 PeakPagefileUsage 10268672 PagefileUsage 245760

видимо в байтах (т.к. делал malloc(10000000)).

Comment: Да, там размер в байтах выдается.